# Why is Go connecting to a database synchronously?

Tags: go

I'm coming from a Node background and trying to get into Go, by looking at code examples.

I do find it weird that code is mostly synchronous - even things like connecting and communicating with the database, e.g.

```
func main() {
    // Create a new client and connect to the server
    client, err := mongo.Connect(context.TODO(), options.Client().ApplyURI(uri))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Doesn't this block the thread until DB sends back a response? If not, how is that possible?

Comment: `Doesn't this block the thread until DB sends back a response?` Yes. `I do find it weird that code is mostly synchronous` Different languages work differently.

Comment: Why would it not be synchronous? If you want to do things concurrently, you have to write the code accordingly. Using a language with concurrency or threading support doesn't magically compile into a highly concurrent binary

Answer (score 2):

Yeah there's this difference:

In Node everything is not blocking until you say it otherwise, `await` or callabck.

In Go everything is blocking until you say it otherwise, `go`.

Comment: So wouldn't that be a problem when we have many concurrent requests, .e.g in a web server?

Comment: @JuntaA No, because those are explicitly concurrent. IMO it makes much more sense to have things be blocking by default. What if the database connection returns an error? If it is concurrent, you would have to write a lot more code to catch that error between different threads.

Comment: That's why each request has separate goroutine. To compare it with node, a lotof express code can't handle 2 request, just open a infinite loop in one request and program can't process any other request. I think it's very important to having concurrency without much code but explicit concurrency request is better IMO.

Comment: That makes sense - because each request is handled by a separate goroutine, that allows for blocking code. Thanks!